# R - How to plot a graph from bool values

Tags: r, plot

So, I have a vector full of 1s and 0s. I need to plot a graph that starts at (0, 0) and rises by 1 for every 1 in the vector and dips by 1 for every 0 in the vector. For example if my vector is [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ] I should get something that looks like

[image]

I thought about creating another vector that would hold the sum of the first i elements of the original vector at index i (from the example: [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6 ]) but that would not account for the dips at 0s. Also, I cannot use loops to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert the zeros to -1, add a zero at the very beginning to make sure it starts from [0,0] and then plot the cumulative sum:

```
#starting vec
myvec <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
#convert 0 to -1
myvec[myvec == 0] <- -1
#add a zero at the beginning to make sure it starts from [0,0]
myvec <- c(0, myvec)
#plot cumulative sum
plot(cumsum(myvec), type = 'line')
#points(cumsum(myvec)) - if you also want the points on top of the line
```

[image]